# Programmatically naming outputs from the QGIS Modeler?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, batch, qgis-modeler

I am attempting my first use of the modeler from the Graphical Modeler from the Processing menu in QGIS (2.18.3). I made a simple model for using meanshift segmentation. It just has a raster input and the algorithm for the segmentation.

I have several small rasters that I want to segment and so I want to run this iteratively through the rasters. I am not sure how that is done, so I am trying to run the model as a batch process. The batch parameters require me to name an output for each line. It seems tedious to have to write out a path and name for each output. I don't know how to simplify this. In ArcGIS' model builder, I add a generic name with an iterator to just number each new file. The iterator in that modeler is %i%. How should I use the process model to iterate through the list? Is batch processing the right way? How do I designate the names for the output without typing each out individually? I'd be fine if the process just referenced back to the raster names.

EDIT after Oto's answer. I don't get that menu from `...`. I only get a Save window as shown. You can see that I clicked in the `...`. I right-clicked and left-clicked and didn't get the save options that you show in your answer. [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hit the `...` button, set output file name and save like with usual saving single file. This create a basis for the files names. After hitting`Save` the `Autofill settings` should appear.

There you can choose fill with values from any parameter or autofill by numbers, which creates suffix to your output name.

[image]

Comment: Oto, that looks like it would work, but I don't get that kind of response from the `...` and I am not sure how to fix that.

Comment: You have to fill the `File name` and Save, like usual saving files, than the autofiller should appear.

Comment: You're welcome :), I edited the answer so now it should be clearer.

Comment: this works but is it possible to add text AFTER original filename?

Right now it is: "myText_originalFilename" but I want "original_Filename_myText"

Answer (score 5):

In QGIS 3.8 you can do more complicated file naming in the bulk processor using **calculate by expression**. Rather than hitting the `...` you can do the **Autofill...** drop down and select **calculate by expression** and in the expression choose the field with your original file and add the text you want before or after the field.
For example this expression adds degradation_ in front of my input file name (landuse_NY) in the **input** field:

```
'C:/Users/BP/Desktop/' || 'Degradation_' || @input ||'.tif'
```

Resulting in **degradation_landuse_NY.tif**

And this expression uses a regular expression to take the text after the last underscore in the file name and tack it on to **degradation**.

```
'C:/Users/BP/Desktop/' || 'Degradation' || regexp_substr( @input ,'(?:.(?!_))+$')||'.tif'
```

Resulting in **Degradation_NY.tif**